# E/SelfBrailleClient(11344): Failed to bind to service

Tags: android

I keep getting following error in Logcat of my Android apps.

```
08-18 12:20:10.030: E/SelfBrailleClient(11344): Failed to bind to service
08-18 12:20:10.450: E/SelfBrailleClient(11344): Failed to bind to service
08-18 12:20:10.650: E/SelfBrailleClient(11344): Failed to bind to service
08-18 12:20:10.650: E/SelfBrailleClient(11344): Failed to bind to service
08-18 12:20:10.650: E/SelfBrailleClient(11344): Failed to bind to service
08-18 12:20:10.981: E/SelfBrailleClient(11344): Failed to bind to service
08-18 12:20:11.942: E/SelfBrailleClient(11344): Failed to bind to service
08-18 12:20:11.942: E/SelfBrailleClient(11344): Failed to bind to service
08-18 12:20:11.942: E/SelfBrailleClient(11344): Failed to bind to service
```

I seem to notice this in several of my applications.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you solved the problem? I have the same error log, and the WebView load blank page!

Comment: @Bill unfortunately I didn't find a solution.

Comment: @SudhirKhanger did you find a solution for this yet?